# How to use output variable of one task under a job as a condition to next job's task in azure-yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have written a powershell script task under a job in same stage to find the $initialFile from my below script and perfrom few operations.I would like to set a output variable of my powershell script. so that I can use it as a condition in my following copy & publish task. In summary I would like to perform ProcessTestResults only when powershell task finds $initialFile
Here is my yaml file:

```
Stage: Azure 
-jobs:
 -job: A

- task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: 'find failed tests and copy them'
              name: passOutput
              inputs:
                workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/Tests/E2EAutomationTests/Logs
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  Write-Host "Current Working Directory:"
                  Write-Host (Get-Location)
 
                  Write-Host "Contents of the Current Directory:"
                  Get-ChildItem
 
                  $currentDirectory = Get-Location
                  $initialFileName = "failedTests.txt"
                  $targetFolder = ".\FailedTestCopy" 
                  $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDirectory -Directory
                 $script= foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                      $folderPath = $folder.FullName
                      $aTxtFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter $initialFileName -File | Select-Object -First 1
                      if (-not $aTxtFile) {
                          throw "No '$initialFileName' found in the folder '$($folder.Name)'."
                  } else {
                      $destination = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath            Write-Host "Destination directory created: $destination"
                  
                  }
                  }

- job:  ProcessTestResults
          displayName: 'Process Test Results'
          dependsOn: A
          condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.E2E_test.outputs['passOutput.script'], 'true'))
          steps:
            - task: CopyFiles@2           
              displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.targetfolder }}/TestArtifacts'

              inputs:
                sourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\$(Build.BuildId)\Tests\E2EAutomationTests\Logs\FailedTestCopy'
                contents: |
                 **/failedTests.txt
                  **/*.txt
                  **/*.etl
                
                TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.targetfolder }}/TestResults'
                OverWrite: true
              continueOnError: true
```

I have tried using the following conditions in copy task
condition: failed()
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.E2E_test.outputs['passOutput.script'], 'true'))
But the evaluation is coming as null

Output of ProcessTestResults Job :
Expanded: and(True, eq(Null, 'true'))
Result: False

Comment: You're not setting an output variable. Did you look at the documentation on how to use output variables?

Comment: I have set an flag $output=false in my updated powershell script .Please find below.
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                      $folderPath = $folder.FullName
                      $aTxtFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter $initialFileName -File -Recurse
                      $output = $false
                      if (-not $aTxtFile) {
                          $output = $true
                          return $output
                          break
                  } else {

Comment: See my previous comment: **Look at the documentation**. That is not how you set an output variable that is recognized in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: I have also set variable as below:
Please correct me if I am wrong 
Stage : A
variables:
         output: false

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to set a output variable of my powershell script. so that I can use it as a condition in my following copy & publish task.

Step1:

You need to using [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#examples-1) to set variable (with `isOutput=true`) in your powershell script in your **first** job.  For example, use `$initialFileFound` value to indicate if the file is found or not.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialFileFound;isoutput=true]yes"
```

You can use it in if else in your powershell task(for example)

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'find failed tests and copy them'
    name: passOutput
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/Tests/E2EAutomationTests/Logs
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
      ......
        if (-not $aTxtFile) {
          Write-Host "No '$initialFileName' found in the folder '$($folder.Name)'."
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialFileFound;isoutput=true]no"
        } else {
            $destination = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath
            Write-Host "Destination directory created: $destination"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialFileFound;isoutput=true]yes"
          }
        }
```

Step2:

In next job, invoke the output variable in condition expression.

```
  - job:  ProcessTestResults
    displayName: 'Process Test Results'
    dependsOn: A
    condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.initialFileFound'], 'yes') #map initialFileFound and check the value
    steps:
    .....
```

If file is NOT found, the next job is skipped:

[image]

You can find more details in official doc [Use the output variable from a job in a condition in a subsequent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job).

Edit:

1. Fix the stage, job syntax error.
2. The default working directory is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s`(with s), also `$(Build.BuildId)` points to build id which will be `changed` for every build. Do you generate the directory dynamically in the build? If not, please double confirm if the working directory on your yaml is expected. For test, I have folder structure as below in repo:

[image]

3. You use `foreach` to check the file in every folder, it will override the variable value if you define variable in if&else expression. I add `break` to jump out once the file is found. Please consider your real situation about this.
4. I add a step to check the variable value, to confirm it has value.

The full yaml:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest
stages:
  - stage: Azure
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'find failed tests and copy them'
          name: passOutput
          inputs:
            workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/TestFolder1'
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
                Write-Host "Current Working Directory:"
                Write-Host (Get-Location)
 
                Write-Host "Contents of the Current Directory:"
                Get-ChildItem
 
                $currentDirectory = Get-Location
                $initialFileName = "failedTests.txt"
                $targetFolder = ".\FailedTestCopy" 
                $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDirectory -Directory
                foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                    $folderPath = $folder.FullName
                    $aTxtFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter $initialFileName -File -Recurse
                      
                    if (-not $aTxtFile) {
                        Write-Host "No '$initialFileName' found in the folder '$($folder.Name)'."
                        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialFileFound;isoutput=true]no"

                  } else {
                      $destination = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath $folder.Name
                      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination | Out-Null
                      Write-Host "Destination directory created: $destination"
                      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialFileFound;isoutput=true]yes"
                      break       # add break here if the file is found, otherwise it will check for all folders if the file exists, and overwrite the variable.
                  }
                  }

        - script: |
            echo $(passOutput.initialFileFound)
          displayName: Checkthevalue

      - job:  ProcessTestResults
        displayName: 'Process Test Results'
        dependsOn: A
        condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.initialFileFound'], 'yes')
        steps:
          - script: echo test
```

File found:

[image]

File Not found:

[image]

Comment: tried your suggested solution. evaluated to Expanded: eq(Null, 'yes').Should I declare any $initialFileFound =Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialFileFound;isoutput=true]yes"
under stage variable  ?. I am little confused

Comment: No declare needed, just add the two setvariable commands in your if&else expression in 1st job. `Null` means the variable value is not correctly set, or used incorrect condition expression. Did you use same if&else content , condition expression as mine? You can add the current script and pipeline execution screenshot which could benifit for troubleshooting.

Comment: [https://github.com/Ssirivoru2442/azure-devops1]

Please find the attached repo, I have added the file and screenshot

Comment: I fixed some syntax issue on your yaml, and add `break` when the file is found.(since you are using foreach loop, it will check all folders and overwrite the variable value).  Also please check the `workingDirectory` value,  details above.  Add a new task to validate the variable value.

Comment: Yes, my working directory will have some folder generated dynamically for every build for example (2023-12-21-16-11-59-test).So, I have to find the $initialFile in the generated directory and do further operations. 
I tried refactoring the code and the Checkthevalue is coming as true. but ProcessTestResults still evaluates to false.I have updated the file in the repo. Kindly, have a look and let me know if any changes needed

Comment: The github link is broken, could you please share the current code and pipeline result screenshot? If the Checkthevalue in `A` job has correct value, it means it has been set correctly. Did you use same condition expression as mine for 2nd job? If you set the variable to `true` or `false`, in the condition expression, please change value `yes` to `true` since it's changed.